# Are chess grand masters automatically checkers grandmasters?

Tags: grandmaster

I couldn't find what the definition of a Checkers GM is exactly so I was wondering if it has the same requirements as chess (2500 points). Also, I was wondering if chess GMs are automatically considered checkers GMs

Comment: As chess and checkers aren't the same, why would a chess master be a checkers master automatically?

Comment: No. They are different games, and there's no real overlap.. A better question is, "which chess grandmasters are also checkers grandmasters?:

Answer (score 5):

No. Chess grand master titles are awarded by the FIDE; see the [FIDE Title Regulations effective from 1 July 2014](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?view=article&id=174). FIDE only awards titles in chess.

Checkers titles are awarded by the FMJD (World Draughts Federation); see the FMJD's [FMJD Regulations for recognition of international titles](https://fmjd.org/docs/Annexes/Annex%2010%20norms%20and%20titles.pdf). FMJD only awards titles in checkers/draughts.

Answer (score 0):

The game of chess is much different from the game of checkers. Chess grand masters are not necessarily checkers grand masters.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example if Ronaldo is the best in soccer does not mean he is the best in the NBA (even though he can jump higher then most nba players) in conclusion ronaldo is the GOAT and To answer your question NOO.